# Downgrade to tmux 2.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: downgrade, tmux

So I'm trying to set up Cloud9 with a new ubuntu instance and it requires tmux 2.1 or earlier and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to downgrade from this new 3.0 version to tmux 2.1.

Any chance one of y'all could lend a hand! :)

Comment: This is exactly why I like to isolate things with docker containers and not downgrade system software to ancient versions. My advice would be to run the Cloud9 instance in a container (Docker, LXD or whatever), and thus in an isolated environment, only exposing what you need. https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/cloud9

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install five year old software, that version is in 16.04, it will never work. As has been suggested a virtual machine is your best option for this, either that or run modern versions of the software.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tmux+&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all